# Jump to next Input when "period" or "slash" is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement a simple Javascript that will cause the focus to jump to the next input box with a particular CSS class when the "period" or "slash" (`.` `/`) keys are pressed.

The input boxes with the class `userinput` are the 20 boxes underneath the "IP Address" column on the following page, to the left of the Check/Show buttons.

http://www.practicalnetworking.net/subnet2.html

Here is the script I added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      // Jump to next box on keypress: period
      $(window).load(function(){
        var currentBoxNumber = 0;
        $(".userinput").keyup(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 190) {
                textboxes = $("input.userinput");
                currentBoxNumber = textboxes.index(this);
                console.log(textboxes.index(this));
                if (textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] != null) {
                    nextBox = textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1];
                    nextBox.focus();
                    nextBox.select();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
      });
</script>
```

I got the script from this JFiddle, and it works perfectly fine in the JFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qLc8851f/

I got a keycode of 190 for `.` on this site:

http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

I got 191 for `/`, but haven't added that into the code yet. Still trying to get it to work with the `.`.

Disclaimer, I am a javascript newb. So please consider explaining the solution like I'm 5 =).  Thank you.

Comment: You realize browsers already implement this with tab and shift-tab, right?

Comment: Your inputs don't have the needed `userinput` class.  Once you add jquery to your page, you'll need to add `class="userinput"` to each input you want to participate.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Yes. But the user's are inserting IP addresses, and its natural to hit "period" between each octet.

Comment: @ShaneCoder Yikes. Big oversight. Had that on my locally hosted HTML, I guess it didn't make it to the uploaded page.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webdev tools included in any browser are very helpful in debugging problems such as this. When I opened your page, the console said "$ is not defined". You need to include jQuery!

Comment: Doh! I figured it was something simple. Thanks Aurel!